# How are top users selected in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I would like to know the selection of process of choosing the top users in any Tag (eg: Java) in Stackoverflow. I know that its dependent upon the number of questions one answers and there is also something called as Point (is this different from Reputation points ?)

Comment: secret incantations and rituals, often involving Unicorns and @Bart

Comment: hahaha....I wish there was a manual describing the same :P

Comment: There is no selection process; the only factor is upvotes on answers/questions in a specific tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the top users on a tag the users are considered for asking questions and answering them seperately. Within each of these sections they are then ordered by net upvotes gained in that tag from that activity (asking or answering)

[image]

Comment: To be perfectly precise, it's "upvotes" rather than "reputation" (as the latter can be cut off by the daily rep cap)

Comment: @Pekka a fair point, edited. The fact skeet only had 581 should have given that away

Comment: Editing the screen shot will have to wait till tomorrow however for now it is time to sleep

Comment: @Pëkka: ??? Doesn't Skeet have less upvotes?

Comment: @Qantas the left hand column is upvotes, the right hand one is answers

Comment: @Pëkka: facepalm, yes.